# What tools can I use to troubleshoot Crypto API calls on an app?

Tags: cryptography, windows-xp, cryptoapi

Windows XP | CryptoAPI

I'm trying to troubleshoot why a `CryptUnprotectData` cryptoAPI call is failing on a Windows app. Is there any way I can monitor the call (and error response from Windows)?  I see that Microsoft has a Capimon utility but as far as I can tell, this tool doesn't include support for monitoring this specific call.

Ideally, I'm looking for a third-party troubleshooting tool (or log).

Comment: maybe the call to GetLastError() will give hints about the problem